# Are there predifined styles for making arrow buttons in windows phone 7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, styles

I want to make some buttons in my app that look like the common round buttons with the arrows found all over the win 7 apps. Anyone know where I can find resources for these?

**UPDATE**

Here's a great tutorial on creating round buttons in WP7. This is exactly what I was trying to do, but I will use the images mentioned by John Gardner below:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/08/13/creating-round-button-for-wp7-part-1.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/08/14/creating-round-image-button-for-wp7-part-1.aspx

Thakns!

Comment: untagged silverlight-4.0, tagged silverlight.  winphone doesn't use sl4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The windows phone 7 sdk installer puts the default icons into \Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.0\Icons

Are those what you're looking for?

Comment: I think that's what I'm looking for. There defined as "Dark" and "Light" which I'm assuming is in case the theme changes. How do I change the images if the theme changes? Or do I even need to?

Comment: You don't need to the white icons are always used they are re-coloured by the system to be black if they appear on the Application Bar, elsewhere you need to use both versions and detect the theme accordingly.

Comment: @Micah you can detect light or dark theme using the method documented at http://mobileworld.appamundi.com/blogs/peterfoot/archive/2010/09/17/determine-light-or-dark-theme-with-wp7-rtm.aspx